# Link empties together using rigid body constraint

Tags: rigid-body-simulation, rigidbody, empty

How would one "Link empties together using a rigid body constraint" ? I am following the instructions someone gave me and having trouble understanding what they meant. All help is appreciated ^_^
[image: Screenshot of given instructions]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the Scene tab you have to create a Rigid body World and select the collection where your objects are.
[image]

Then on the Physics tab you can add a Rigid body constraint and change the type to hinge. I assume that's what they meant
[image]